# Sudden drop of CPU performance on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, performance, cpu

I own a Poweredge R620 server with 2x Intel Xeon CPU E5-2695 v2 @ 2.40GHz

This server was perfectly working for years without issue. It was reinstalled with a fresh ubuntu 20.04 10 months ago and was working perfectly since then, hosting about 15 Virtual Machines with KVM without issues.

One day, without any specific action, all VM suddendly increased their CPU usage. At the same time, power consumption of the server decreased drastically.

Initially we were thinking that a specific VM was the culprit, but after moving all VMs to another similar servers, it appears that all VM were perfectly working.

I made some test on the server (sysbench aso). and CPU performances are really bad : This Xeon 2695V2 is reported as 10x less performant than a E5-2620V2

During sysbench, /proc/cpuinfo show a frequency for all cores between 150MHz(!) and 1GHz... This is not supposed to be possible according to CPU specification

```
cpufreq-info (example last core 47)
analyzing CPU 47 :
driver : intel_pstate
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 47
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 47
maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
hardware limits : 1.20 GHz - 3.20 GHz
available cpufreq governors : performance, powersave
current policy :  frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.20 GHz.
              The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
current CPU frequency: 482 MHz.
```

It shows that CPU is in performance state, but current frequency is only 482MHz whereas it was supposed to be between 1.2 GHz et 3.2GHz

I'm quite sure that rebooting the server will solve the issue, but i'd like to understand what is happening.

Nothing in the logs. CPU temperature is normal (and doesn't change during stress test!).

Using intel_reg_pp during load give following results :

```
+----+------------------------------+---------+----------+
|  # | MSR Register                 | Address |   Core 0 |
+----+------------------------------+---------+----------+
|  0 | IA32_PERF_CTL                |   0x199 |      c00 |
|  1 | IA32_CLOCK_MODULATION        |   0x19A |        0 |
|  2 | IA32_THERM_INTERRUPT         |   0x19B |        3 |
|  3 | IA32_HWP_THERM_STATUS        |   0x19C | 88310c00 |
|  4 | IA32_MISC_ENABLE             |   0x1A0 |   850089 |
|  5 | IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_MARGIN    |   0x1A1 |     1db0 |
|  6 | IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET      |   0x1A2 |   571000 |
|  7 | IA32_PKG_THERM_STATUS        |   0x1B1 | 882d0c00 |
|  8 | MSR_PKG_ENERGY_STATUS        |   0x611 | 5f8a8ad6 |
|  9 | MSR_PKG_STATUS               |   0x613 |  4d678f3 |
| 10 | MSR_PPERF                    |   0x64E |      N/A |
| 11 | MSR_CORE_PERF_LIMIT_REASONS  |   0x690 |      N/A |
| 12 | IA32_PM_ENABLE               |   0x770 |      N/A |
| 13 | IA32_HWP_CAPABILITIES        |   0x771 |      N/A |
| 14 | IA32_HWP_REQUEST_PKG         |   0x772 |      N/A |
| 15 | IA32_HWP_INTERRUPT           |   0x773 |      N/A |
| 16 | IA32_HWP_REQUEST             |   0x774 |      N/A |
| 17 | IA32_HWP_PECI_REQUEST_INFO   |   0x775 |      N/A |
| 18 | IA32_HWP_STATUS              |   0x777 |      N/A |
+----+------------------------------+---------+----------+
```

And with turbostat (PkgWatt and PKG_% are sum of both processor packages. Both processor packages are sharing really similar behaviour)

```
turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,IRQ,PKG_% --interval 2
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt PKG_%
9.86    1494    15787   39  59.64   104.12
9.97    1458    12634   41  59.12   102.13
9.83    1487    14591   39  60.29   102.96
8.46    1586    13092   39  59.51   95.38
10.79   1463    14587   40  59.82   96.83
11.27   1438    12438   39  59.48   100.01 
turbostat: cpu0 jitter 5352 94208         <- Applying load
turbostat: cpu24 jitter 5104 94992
turbostat: cpu2 jitter 94840 5192
... lots of similar jitter messages
31.74   593     16989   39  54.99   125.91
... jitter message again...
99.20   288     41031   39  66.21   194.88
99.13   403     36165   40  68.07   189.75
99.81   458     32915   40  70.00   190.04
99.21   503     36909   41  72.91   194.20
99.26   528     36361   40  71.29   187.86
99.02   575     39900   41  74.99   193.81
98.34   605     40204   40  73.76   188.68
69.67   684     35305   40  78.59   134.74
13.41   1678    22536   40  66.61   0.97   <- Load Removed
8.77    1617    12158   39  61.00   22.58
8.53    1611    12454   39  60.03   65.16
10.47   1440    14426   40  59.05   92.75
12.00   1387    9389    40  59.17   101.51
```

turbostat without quiet option

```
turbostat version 19.08.31 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0xd CPUID levels; 0x80000008 xlevels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3e:4 (6:62:4)
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, No-HWP, No-HWPnotify, No-HWPwindow, No-HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, No-EPB
cpu36: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): No-SGX
cpu36: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00400000 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 570 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 115 Watts
cpu36: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0xc10e4811800
12 * 100.0 = 1200.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
24 * 100.0 = 2400.0 MHz base frequency
cpu36: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x25000059 (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu36: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT1: 0x1c1c1c1c1c1c1c1c
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 16 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 15 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 14 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 13 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 12 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 11 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 10 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 9 active cores
cpu36: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x1c1c1c1c1d1e1f20
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 8 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 7 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
28 * 100.0 = 2800.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
29 * 100.0 = 2900.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
30 * 100.0 = 3000.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
31 * 100.0 = 3100.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
32 * 100.0 = 3200.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu36: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x00008400 (locked, pkg-cstate-limit=0 (pc0))
cpu36: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu36: C1: MWAIT 0x00
cpu36: C1E: MWAIT 0x01
cpu36: C3: MWAIT 0x10
cpu36: C6: MWAIT 0x20
cpu36: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu36: cpufreq governor: performance
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu36: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a1003 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000015 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x2f05a002000398 (115 W TDP, RAPL 64 - 180 W, 0.045898 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x68450005a8398 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (115.000000 Watts, 10.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (138.000000 Watts, 0.007812* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_INFO,: 0x2f00fc006800e2 (28 W TDP, RAPL 13 - 32 W, 0.045898 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu1: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a1003 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000015 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu1: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x2f05a002000398 (115 W TDP, RAPL 64 - 180 W, 0.045898 sec.)
cpu1: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x68450005a8398 (UNlocked)
cpu1: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (115.000000 Watts, 10.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu1: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (138.000000 Watts, 0.007812* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu1: MSR_DRAM_POWER_INFO,: 0x2f00fc006800e2 (28 W TDP, RAPL 13 - 32 W, 0.045898 sec.)
cpu1: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu1: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu1: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu1: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu1: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x00571000 (87 C)
cpu1: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x00571000 (87 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x88300c00 (39 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (87 C, 87 C)
cpu1: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x88380c00 (31 C)
cpu1: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (87 C, 87 C)
cpu36: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu36: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu36: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
```

Comment: No experience of this but is there a CMOS battery that has never been changed? Odd things happened on one of my systems when a new battery was needed

Comment: When CPU frequencies go below the spec sheets minimums, it typically means Clock Modulation has engaged. The reason is typically due to a thermal event. Look for any "temperature" related messages anywhere in `/var/log`, say `/var/log/kern.log`. You could also do `sudo rdmsr -a 0x1a2` and edit your question with the results.

Comment: I added results for intel_reg_pp (rdmsr -a 0x1a2 five 57100)

Comment: If you don't flag me in a comment, I don't know to come and look, @Golgot. Anyway, I asked for the wrong MSR, but you got the right one anyhow. No Clock Modulation on the listed core. I have not seen the jitter message in turbostat for years, and even then it was only because of bad turbostat code. I'll have to look at the code to remember what it means.

Comment: I haven't decoded all the bits, but some indicate power limit throttling, which also PKG_% supports. Indeed, PkgWatt of 66 @288 MHz does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you @DougSmythies! Do you know what I can do for further investigation? Server bios (omreport report no issue). I'm quite sure that rebooting will solve the issue but I deeply prefer to find root cause to prevent it.

Comment: The high Processor Package power at what is reported to be extremely low CPU frequency is very worrying.  I do not know where to look next. Try turbostat without the --quiet option, so we can see the startup spew of information.

Comment: Thank you @DougSmythies. What is very strange for me is that both CPU seems to be concerned? i uploaded turbostat

Comment: Nothing odd (at least, that I notice) in the turbostat startup spew. The jitter messages are when there is a lot of latency between system calls to read mperf and aperf. You are using a rather old version of turbostat, and I did not look at the history to see when jitter code changed. Regardless, the numbers printed indicate huge differences, something is very wrong.

Comment: For example, if I force the jitter message, this is what I get (i5-10600K): `turbostat: cpu7 jitter 1028 704` (and I cherry picked one of the worst differences). The units here are TSC clocks (I think), 4.1 GHz for me, and 2.4GHz for you. Under heavy load, again cherry picked `turbostat: cpu7 jitter 6629 1106`.

Comment: Hummmm. I will probably try to reboot and wait and see... @DougSmythies, just a question about PKGWATT, is value the sum for both CPU, one CPU (which one?), a median value?

Comment: Ok, without summary, I see that this is 66W for both CPU (33W+33W).

Comment: Did you ever re-boot, and the issue persists? Or are you still trying to figure it before re-booting?

Comment: Do your processors have MSR 0X64F? If yes please provide contents under your bad conditions of operation.

Comment: @DougSmythies : reboot is scheduled start of next week, I was still trying to figure out before replacement of the motherboard if I have no more information.. MSR 0x64F is not available

Comment: So, after reboot everything went back to normal... I will probable swap the motherboard to avoid further issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reboot, problem was solved and this issue never occured again for 2 years without changing the hardware.